# How secure is encrypting files with blowfish?

Tags: security, encryption

I know using `:set cryptmethod=zip` is *not* secure, but how secure is using `:set cryptmethod=blowfish`?

On [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_(cipher)) I read that the blowfish cipher, as such, should be secure, but this says nothing about the security of Vim's *implementation* of it.

And what about swapfiles, backupfiles, undofiles, and other possible ways to bypass the blowfish encryption? How secure is Vim there?

Comment: Won't this really be better off at [security.se], given that you have already identified the algorithm(s) being used?

Comment: Hmm. The docs are a bit confusing here. `:h encryption` says undo and swap files are encrypted in both [7.3](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#encryption) and [7.4](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#encryption), yet [`:h cryptmethod`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27cryptmethod%27) in 7.4 makes explicit mention of the `undo` file only for `blowfish2`.

Comment: @muru It's a question about Vim's implementation of blowfish-based encryption, not about the blowfish algorithm itself. This question would also be on-topic on [security.se], but that doesn't make it off-topic here. The answer is, in fact, that blowfish itself is secure (even if it isn't the best choice), but that Vim's implementation of it is bad.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is *not* secure. David Leadbeater posted POC code to brute-force upto 64 bytes in an article titled, somewhat ironically, [*Vim blowfish encryption... or why you shouldn't roll your own crypto*](https://dgl.cx/2014/10/vim-blowfish). The Vim documentation [now recommends](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#encryption):

```
- The implementation of 'cryptmethod' "blowfish" has a flaw.  It is possible
  to crack the first 64 bytes of a file and in some circumstances more of the
  file. Use of it is not recommended, but it's still the strongest method
  supported by Vim 7.3 and 7.4.  The "zip" method is even weaker.
```

And, earlier on:

```
The text in the swap file and the undo file is also encrypted.  E843
However, this is done block-by-block and may reduce the time needed to crack a
password.  You can disable the swap file, but then a crash will cause you to
lose your work.  The undo file can be disabled without much disadvantage. 
        :set noundofile
        :noswapfile edit secrets

Note: The text in memory is not encrypted.  A system administrator may be able
to see your text while you are editing it.  When filtering text with
":!filter" or using ":w !command" the text is also not encrypted, this may
reveal it to others.  The 'viminfo' file is not encrypted.
```

Summary:

- If you care about security, `blowfish` should not be used. Use `blowfish2` or `xchacha20` instead. xchacha20 requires that Vim was built with +sodium, but is the most secure option as it uses the well-known libsodium.
- While `swap` and `undo` files are encrypted, `viminfo` isn't.

Unsolicited advice:

- If you do care about security, *do not roll your own encryption*. And that means the `blowfish2` implementation as well. Use something else, like GPG. The [`gnupg.vim`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3645) plugin may be useful. It seems [to be maintained](https://github.com/jamessan/vim-gnupg). It disables `viminfo` and the swap file.

Comment: The claim by David Leadbeater in (https://dgl.cx/2014/10/vim-blowfish) the last para is using a dictionary for bruteforce attack. He then adds "small passwords" would weak. His theoretical arguments are correct but not practical. Good 64 bit or more random passwords are uncrackable.

Comment: This is incorrect: the point of the dictionary is to attack the plaintext, not the password; it doesn't bruteforce the password at all. Definitely do use gpg or another tool designed for encryption rather than Vim's built-in support.

Comment: @DavidLeadbeater I converted your answer to a comment (you mentioned something about replying to the comment there.) If you feel like posting a full answer to expand on it, please do so. If you do, please include enough context to allow the answer to stand on its own. Thanks for your contribution!